# Mailbox Export Request (PST) in Powershell returning no status

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am attempting to automate PST creation. However, about 50% of the time, I run into an error where this code block is stuck in a endless loop as powershell never retrieves a status for the Export Request.

```
$exportIdentity = New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $userID -FilePath "$path$userID.pst" -BadItemLimit 5000 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty identity
Log-Write "Created mailbox export with identity $exportIdentity"  
do{
    if($debug-eq1){Log-Write "DEBUG - Waiting for the PST to complete - Current Status is $(Get-MailboxExportRequest -Identity "$exportIdentity"|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status)"}
    if((Get-MailboxExportRequest -Identity "$exportIdentity"|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status)-eq"Queued"){
        $exportIdentity | Resume-MailboxExportRequest
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20 

}until((Get-MailboxExportRequest -Identity "$exportIdentity"|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status) -eq "Completed" -OR (Get-MailboxExportRequest -Identity "$exportIdentity"|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status) -eq "Failed" -OR (Get-MailboxExportRequest -Identity "$exportIdentity"|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status) -eq "CompletedWithWarning")
```

The logs write out endless copies of
`DEBUG - Waiting for the PST to complete - Current Status is`. However, the PST completes normally and saves successfully

Edit: It appears this is occurring if the PST is ran immediately (~2 minutes) after another.

Comment: Are you doing any cleanup after your script runs?  [Mailbox requests are not removed automatically](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607298(v=exchg.141).aspx) so you may need to clear them before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is a common issue by MS. You can use something like this:

```
Do {
$status = Get-MailboxExportRequest -name $exportname | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics
$finish = $status.StatusDetail

 write-host $finish
 Start-Sleep 2
 Write-Host "Please wait..."

 }
       Until ($finish -like "Completed")
```

The StatusDetail property has never failed me.